# Add versioning to existing WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing ASP.NET WebAPI project with a controller that looks like this:

```
namespace WebSite.WebApi.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/accounts")]
    public class AgreementsController : ApiController
    {
        // GET ~/api/accounts/xxx
        [Route("{accountId}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string accountId) => Ok( $"Account #{accountId} from default controller");
    }
}
```

I'm calling the action method by using this URL: `/api/accounts/123`

Now, I want to make another version of this controller that would be called if a client appends a certain query string parameter like this: `/api/accounts/123?api-version=2`. The first URL (without `api-version` param) should still lead to the initial controller

I thought I could use [aspnet-api-versioning by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning) by making another controller and using `ApiVersion` attribute like this:

```
namespace WebSite.WebApi.Controllers.V2
{
    [ApiVersion("2")]
    [RoutePrefix("api/accounts")]
    public class AgreementsController : ApiController
    {
        // GET ~/api/accounts/xxx?api-version=2
        [Route("{accountId}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string accountId) => Ok($"Account #{accountId} from V2 controller");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work like that. All the samples on GitHub suggest that I should decorate both my controllers with `ApiVersion` attribute and explicitly use version in both URLs: `/api/accounts/123?api-version=1` and `/api/accounts/123?api-version=2`.

But I need the URL for the 1st controller to remain the same as it is now: `/api/accounts/123`. Is there any way to achieve this with aspnet-api-versioning
library? Or is there some other API versioning library that can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, you just need to tell the versioning framework to [assume a version if you don't specify one in the config](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/API-Versioning-Options#assume-default-version-when-unspecified):

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.AddApiVersioning(versioningConfig =>
    {
        versioningConfig.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    });

    //snip
}
```